# Changing the System Classloader of Weblogic

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I want to change the classloader hierarchy of an application hosted in a weblogic server.
The classes of the JARs located at ***domain_name/lib*** must be the top of System Classloader over the default classes, but a want to do this without using prefer-application-packages inside my module.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this? All jars (with some spec documented exceptions) in the WEB-INF/lib directory of a web module will *always* be made available to that module before any others because it is spec mandated.

Comment: I'm trying to minimize PermGen Space error after a redeploy. Weblogic isn't cleaning old references.

Comment: That problem is as old as Java EE itself. It's often exasperated by applications creating and using unmanaged resources such as threads and database connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always modify startWebLogic.sh script to define which jars load first, however it is not a good practice (it is cleaner to use prefer-application-packages)